# Hide/Show iframes with a button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a webpage with 2 iframes, 1 underneath the other. I would like both iframes hidden when a user first clicks on the webpage. There will be 2 buttons, 1 above each iframe and the user must click on the button to show the iframe. Also I want it so if iframebutton1 is pressed then iframe2 will be hidden (if it's showing) and visa versa.

Here is my code:

jsfiddle.net/darego/Z62P7/

Comment: I have no idea about javascript as of yet. Only HTML and CSS so I wouldn't even know where to start

Comment: googling you'll find out many tutorials about show/hide in javascript, please it is for you ;)

Comment: Essentially, it's just a click toggle with show hide capabilities.  Start there.

Comment: use jsbin/jsfiddle rather then pastebin, or embed the code in your question. there is no need to link to pastebin.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the code that I would recommend using:

```
function hideToggle(button, elem) {
  $(button).toggle( function () {
    $(elem).hide();
  },function () {
    $(elem).show();
  });
}

hideToggle(".button1", ".iframe1");
hideToggle(".button2", ".iframe2");
```

Here is the updated working fiddle: [Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/Z62P7/1/)

This just uses a simple hide/show function so you can reuse it again and again.

Comment: how do i link that jQuery with my button mate?

Comment: `.element` is your button.

Comment: `.toggle()` can also be used to show/hide depending on the current state. Anyway, jQuery was not asked in the question.

Comment: @SethenMaleno thanks a lot for the reply! i have tried it but nothing happens when i try it in chrome. here is what i tried: http://pastebin.com/3eT30evd

Comment: @pimvdb thanks for the reply. i do not mind using jQuery, once it gets the job done

Comment: here is my code (tried it for the 2 buttons and it still doesn't work for some reason): http://pastebin.com/rC4T01tJ

Comment: @Craig You need to link the jQuery library using the `<script src="#"></script>` in your `head` element.  Other than that, it looks right.

Comment: Calm down :) I mean that including jQuery just for this is overkill if the OP is not using it.

Comment: @SethenMaleno thanks again for the reply and your time. i got the latest jQuery library and linked it in the <head> although it still does not work.. any idea why? here is my latest HTML code: pastebin.com/RBkYZStm

Comment: @Craig Create a jsfiddle with all of your updated code so we can test it easier.

Comment: @SethenMaleno
http://jsbin.com/welcome/68441/edit there you go. hope i did it right

edit: here is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/darego/Z62P7/

Comment: @Craig Check my edited answer, has a working fiddle included.

Comment: @SethenMaleno you, my friend are a legend :) can't thank you enough. unfortunately i can't up vote your answer as i don't have 15 rep. thanks again!

Comment: @Craig Haha.  Thanks man!  I added one to your original question, so now you only have 2 points to go.  When you do get to 15, try to remember to up vote if you can!  Glad I could help!

Comment: @JoeB. The original fiddle provided by Craig was an attempt to  solve his issue wth jQuery.  The answer I provided builds upon his work to solve his issue.  You can downvote if you'd like, but I believe it's for an invalid reason, since his question was looking to use jQuery and not necessarily vanilla JavaScript.

Answer (score 9):

To show or hide iframes:

```
document.getElementById("yourIFrameid").style.display = "none"; //hides the frame
document.getElementById("yourIFrameid").style.display = "block"; //shows the frame
```