# IFrame and Video Streaming Consuming my website bandwidth?

Tags: javascript, iframe, video-streaming, bandwidth

I created a website with some pages containing Iframes that stream videos. I'm planning to host my website at a webhost that indicate me that i only have a limited amount of BW per month, my question is:

suppose i have 1000 users per/ day and the users watch all the videos in Iframes (10 Iframes watched per user in a day)
do the iframe streaming consume my website bandwidth that the webhost allowed me? i have 20 GB of allowed traffic ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are not hosting the videos, they will not use your webhosts bandwidth.

Comment: So i can add as many i frame as i want in a single page and the users can watch whithout destroying my bandwidth ? that's cool thanks :)

Comment: Exactly, assuming the contents in the iframe are external to your webhost... which from your post I am assuming is the case!

Comment: Neat ! could you please give me your advice, in this page a regrouped all the 10 iframe in one page but i want to hide them so when a user click on a hyperlinkm the iframe shows up automatically in the same whithout the user leaving my website

Comment: There are lots of way to do that, one of the simplest ways is explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113850/hide-show-iframes-with-a-button

Answer (score 1):

What's in the iFrames?

HTTP Transfers from your host are the only thing consuming your bandwidth.
So if the "src" of your iframe is say youtube, that is the same as the user being on youtubes site, just framed in your site.

Now if you plan to host videos yourself, you will need a ton of bandwidth and probably some sort of cloud, edge, location based server type stuff and an IT department.

Comment: alriiight, but no i'm not hosting the videos they are on youtube, thanks