# Wordpress link onclick show/hide iframe

Tags: html, wordpress, iframe, show-hide

Is it possible to show /hide iframe when user clicks on a link? I've used it to show hide .jpg files but with an iframe it doesnt seem to work..

```
<h3><a onclick="wp_showhide.main(this, 'spoiler1')" href="javascript:void(0)">
 ["Show", "Hide", "invisible"]
</a></h3>
 <div id="spoiler1">
 <a href="http://www.newyorker.com/online/blogs/photobooth/NASAEarth-  01.jpg">
 <img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-56" alt="Image"   src="http://www.newyorker.com/online/blogs/photobooth/NASAEarth-01.jpg" width="1291"    height="783" />
</a>
</div>
```

Please help

Comment: Have you tried looking at this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113850/hide-show-iframes-with-a-button

Specifically the response from Sethen Maleno

Comment: Yeap.. For some reason it's not working.. ((

Comment: To be honest, You can use jQuery instead of an Iframe. http://papermashup.com/simple-jquery-showhide-div/

Check this tutorial out

Comment: Separately works great! ..But on a wordpress page - refuses to do the same. It displays content on pageload and clicking show/hide doesnt affect it in anyway...(((

Comment: Have you tried manipulating a Wordpress page template? You can create a custom one then when you go to add new page select template and use it. Publish and all the code should be working for you.

Comment: Heeey! Got it working! Had to get rid of all empty lines in the code... A bit strange behavior, but... it worked! Thanks Bradly!