# Toggle view of iframe with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

The goal is to toggle the view/appearence of an `iframe` using a button or anchor.

Using [Sethen's fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z62P7/1/) posted in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14113959/9710118), I created my own version.
It's working just fine with jQuery 1.8.3 activated, but not with a newer version like 3.3.1. The button hides on default with 3.3.1 and I can't get it to appear again. I'd be happy to do it without jQuery, but couldn't get it to work.. Any ideas?

[fiddle with 1.8.3:](http://jsfiddle.net/kimneu3000/Z62P7/669/)

[fiddle with 3.3.1](http://jsfiddle.net/kimneu3000/qkv1824o/)

Comment: Code relevant to your question belongs directly into your question, not just dumped on external sites. Please edit accordingly, and go read [ask] if you haven’t done so yet.

Comment: The button hides by default because you wrote `$(button).toggle(...)` which instantly hides your button. Here are [`.toggle()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_toggle.asp) arguments `$(selector).toggle(speed,easing,callback)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the `$(button).toggle(...);` (lines 3-10) function with:

```
$(button).click(function() {
    $(elem).toggle();
  }
);
```

This will toggle the visibility of the element everytime you click the button!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to nest `.toggle()` with other statements. Simply do this:

---

```js
$('.button1').click(function() {
 $('.iframe1').toggle();
});
```

```css
iframe {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
}

button {
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 0;
  background: white;
  font: monospace;
  font-weight: 800;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="button1">toggle</button>

<iframe class="iframe1" src="https://wikipedia.org" name="Wiki" height="267px" width:="375px">your browser doesn't support this technology.</iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery(".second-element").click(function(){
   $("#myFrame").slideToggle( "slow" );
  });
```

```css
#myFrame {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="first-element"><span class="second-element">click here</span>
       <iframe id="myFrame" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d184740.70651647498!2d-79.4609325880845!3d43.65704032314052!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x89d4cb90d7c63ba5%3A0x323555502ab4c477!2sToronto%2C+ON%2C+Canada!5e0!3m2!1sen!2snp!4v1528978884393" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
```