# How to only load iframe when link is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I want to only show the iframe popup when the a class link is clicked.

here is my html and JS

It does nothing when I click the aclass link

not sure why, any idea? I added Updated my JS script but it's still not working correctly, popup doesn't appear when alink is clicked

```js
function showPopup() {
  var popup = document.getElementById("popup");
  popup.style.display = "block";
}

var link = document.querySelector('.funnel_button');
link.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // Prevents the default link behavior
  showPopup();
});
```

```css
#popup {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a class="funnel_button" href="#" onclick="showPopup()">Photos</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<iframe src="#" style="display:none;width:100%;height:100%;border:none;border-radius:4px" id="popup" data-layout="{'id':'POPUP'}" data-trigger-type="alwaysShow" data-trigger-value="" data-activation-type="alwaysActivated" data-activation-value="" data-deactivation-type="neverDeactivate"
  data-deactivation-value="" data-form-name="NAME" data-height="423" data-layout-iframe-id="popup-" data-form-id="13D" title="NAME">
</iframe>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hide/Show iframes with a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113850/hide-show-iframes-with-a-button)

Comment: no.  I updated my post

Comment: You don't need `onclick="showPopup()"` if you have an event listener in the code (which is the better place IMHO)

Comment: Picking a single event handler will help (either inline or addEventListener). Once you decide on that, your code does work. I gave your iframe a border so I could see it open and it opened fine.

Comment: Are you wanting to use the href of the link that is clicked for the source of the iFrame?

Answer (score 1):

Just use classes and it will work.  Sample border and colors just for this site.

```js
function showPopup() {
  const popup = document.getElementById("popup");
  popup.src = 'www.example.com'; //does not work in stack overflow for security reasons.
  popup.classList.add("showme");
}

const link = document.querySelector('.funnel_button');
link.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // Prevents the default link behavior
  showPopup();
});
```

```css
#popup {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#popup.showme {
  display: block;
  border: solid 1px red;
  background-color: #FFFF0033;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a class="funnel_button" href="#">Photos</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<iframe src="#" id="popup" data-layout="{'id':'POPUP'}" data-trigger-type="alwaysShow" data-trigger-value="" data-activation-type="alwaysActivated" data-activation-value="" data-deactivation-type="neverDeactivate" data-deactivation-value="" data-form-name="NAME"
  data-height="423" data-layout-iframe-id="popup-" data-form-id="13D" title="NAME">

</iframe>
```